# Active Record error to create database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec, rspec-rails

In my **spec/rails_helper.rb**, i have the code bellow to create the test database if it doesn`t exits.

```
def database_exists?
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection rescue ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError ? false : true
end
unless database_exists?
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:"#{ENV['RAILS_ENV']}")
  db_config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[ENV['RAILS_ENV']]
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.create_database db_config
end
```

but i got this error when **rspec** is called:

> .rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:23:in `rescue in mysql2_connection': Unknown database 'my-db-test' (ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError)

Where is the problem?

If i use **system('rake db:create')**, it works, but is a good pratice?

Answer (score 3):

The database doesn't exist so to avoid the error you can run:

```
rake db:create
```

or you can run:

```
rake db:setup
```

This will create the database AND run the migration files.

Comment: How can I do it programatically automatically when tests are run?

Comment: For Rails 4.1+, in your **spec/rails_helper.rb** file, you can include `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!`. This automatically syncs your test database with your schema. You can also try running `rake db:test:prepare` in older versions of Rails for the same to clone a test database using your current schema.

Comment: after upgrading to Rails 5.2 I start to see this error exactly when running `rake db:create`, very strange